# Sharing folders on home network between ubuntu machines is not permanent after restart

Tags: networking

I run a home network with a desktop pc and 2 laptops all running ubuntu 11.10. I set up a shared folder on the desktop pc through nautilus -> Sharing options. That folder is readily accessible from the laptops. Sofar creating a shared folder was easy and data exchange works fine in all directions. The problem is that the sharing settings are not permanent and the folder has to be marked as shared every time after restart of the desktop pc. How can I make the folder a permanently shared folder that remains shared after startup of desktop pc. Is there an easy way? (No Windows folder (ntfs) in network, file system is exe4 across all machines, no virtual machines (VBOx) running)

Answer (score 2):

In Nautilus, after you've set up the folder you want, and when you have it open, choose "Bookmarks" from the top menu (global menu if you're using Unity), choose "Add Bookmark."  After that it should be permanent and remain in your list after you reboot.